# Long time to boot in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

It takes almost 6 minutes to boot into Ubuntu 12.04. My laptop is Lenovo Y550P.
I edited the grub menu while booting and tried acpi=off. It still takes the same time. The link shows my dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/PqV06RW4
Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making acquaintances with your:

**Log file viewer**

You might find the answer there. Just check times.